# Flutter: Custom Bottom Navigation Bar Cut Radius

Tags: flutter, cut, radius

I want to cut the parts with radius from **custom** bottom navigation bar just like in design :

[image: design]

But the code works like this :

[image: code works]

This is my code :

```
  // home_page.dart //
  bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavigationBar(),

  // custom_bnb.dart //
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: _buildBoxDecoration,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: AppBorderRadius.bottomBarRadius,
        child: Container(
          height: 80,
          decoration: _buildBoxDecoration,
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              BottomBarItem(iconData: AppIcons.location, title: AppStrings.location),
              BottomBarItem(iconData: AppIcons.home, title: AppStrings.homePage),
              BottomBarItem(iconData: AppIcons.settings, title: AppStrings.settings),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

BoxDecoration get _buildBoxDecoration =>
      BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor, borderRadius: AppBorderRadius.bottomBarRadius, boxShadow: [AppBoxShadow.materialShadow]);

// app_border_radius.dart //
static BorderRadius get bottomBarRadius => BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(50));
```

I tried clipBehavior property in all of container

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for bottomNavigationBar :
You can set the Scaffold's `extendBody` property to `true`

> [Flutter extendBody property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBody.html)

for AppBar:
You can set the Scaffold's `extendBodyBehindAppBar` property to `true`

> [Flutter extendBodyBehindAppBar property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBodyBehindAppBar.html)

Comment: You are legend bro